# Card game probability with simultaneous drawing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From a usual deck of 52 cards we draw 10 cards simultaneously (thus no replacement). What is the probability to have 5 diamonds and a queen?

My attempt: the cardinality of all 10 card possibilities is: $52 \choose 10$. The probability of picking a queen is $4/52$ and the probability of picking 5 diamonds is $13 \choose 5$, finally $36 \choose 4$ ways of picking the last 4 cards. Overall we have then:

$$P=\frac{4/52 * {13 \choose 5} * {36 \choose 4}}{52 \choose 10} = \frac{891}{2417116}$$

Is this correct? Have I mis-counted something due to the fact that among the 5 diamonds the queen of diamond could have already occured (and thus satisfied the queen condition as well)?

I'm having some difficulties as to how translate such questions in terms of union or intersection of simpler events, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How can 2 cards be drawn simultaneously?

Comment: This is not correct because both probabilities, queens and diamonds, are not independent (the diamond queen exists). In any case, if independent, is not 4/52 if not just 4, you are already dividing for all possible hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I call $D$ the random variable to have some number of diamonds in the hand (ten cards) and $Q$ the random variable to have some number of queen in the hand the probability that I want is

$$\Pr[D=5\cap Q=1]$$

We have two different kind of hands for this situation and $D$ and $Q$ are not independent

$$\Pr[D=5\cap Q=1]=\begin{cases}\binom{12}{5}\binom{3}{1}\binom{52-16}{4}\binom{52}{10}^{-1},\ &\text{ if the queen is not diamond}\\\binom{12}{4}\binom{1}{1}\binom{52-16}{5}\binom{52}{10}^{-1},\ &\text{ if the queen is diamond}\end{cases}$$

Add the two cases to have the probability that you want

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes perfect sense. One question about the ways queens can be picked: why is it we have 3 choose 1 and 1 choose 1 instead of 3/52 and 1/52 respectively? It is true that i am already dividing by cardinality of all 10 card hands, but i dont see how this means we dont need to write 1/52 and so on anymore.

Comment: @user929304 3/52 is a probability but 3 choose 1 is a count, not a probability. When we divided by all the cases then becomes a probability, remember $\text{ probability of }X=\frac{\text{number of cases of }X}{\text{all possible cases}}$. You have 3 possible cases when queen is different than diamond, this mean triple number of valid hands (one for each kind of queen that is not diamond). The numerator is the count of all valid hands.

Comment: @user929304 Expand it out $$\frac{\binom{12}{5}\binom{3}{1}\binom{36}{4}}{\binom{52}{10}}= \frac{12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot~~9\cdot~~8\cdot~~3\cdot 36\cdot 33\cdot 32\cdot 31}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 45\cdot 44\cdot 43}\cdot\frac{10!}{5!~1!~4!}$$

Comment: So we don't need to explicitly write $\tfrac {12} {52}$ et cetera, any more, because we can so in an abbreviated form. $~$ The binomial notation is much more compact, and makes it clearer what is being counted.

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes you re right, the expansion ia helpful.

Comment: @Masacroso I just wanted to ask you, if there's a particularly nifty introductory book on practical applications of probabilities (such as these counting problems) that you would recommend? I would be most grateful.

Comment: @user929304 I learn from many diverse books and texts the basics and I only rememeber texts that are not too basic, by example the _Concrete mathematics_ of Graham. But there are a lot of goods free books in the net, I learn just googling, if you dont like a text or the level is too high change to other, this is what I did. Google something like _Introduction to combinatorics_ or _Introduction to probability theory_, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood of getting exactly k diamonds in ten cards is ${{13 \choose k}*{39 \choose 10-k}\over {52 \choose 10}}$.

The odds of getting at least one queen are not independent of the number of diamonds. (For example, if you have 13 diamonds you are sure to have a queen.) Rather, if you have k diamonds, the likelihood that none of them are the queen is ${(13-k)\over 13}$, while the likelihood of the non-diamonds all being non-queen is ${36!/(26+k)!\over 39!/(29+k)!}$.  Therefore, the likelihood of having at least one queen given k diamonds is 1 - ${(13-k)\over 13}*{36!/(26+k)!\over 39!/(29+k)!}$

That being said, the likelihood of getting at least 5 diamonds and at least one queen is $$\sum_{k=5}^{13} {{13 \choose k}*{39 \choose 10-k}\over {52 \choose 10}}*\left(1 - {(13-k)\over 13}*{36!/(26+k)!\over 39!/(29+k)!}\right)$$

Comment: That's for "*at least* five diamonds and one queen" where as the original problem seem to be asking for "exactly" the case. $~$ Still it is a *plausible* interpretation, although I would use complements.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Q{\geq}1\cap\diamondsuit{\geq} 5) ~ = & ~ 1-\mathsf P(Q{=}0\cup \diamondsuit{<}5)\\[2ex] = & ~ 1 - \mathsf P(Q{=}0) - \mathsf P(\diamondsuit{<}5) + \mathsf P(\diamondsuit{<}5\cap Q{=}0)\\[2ex] = & ~ \frac{\dbinom{52}{10}-\dbinom{48}{10}-\sum\limits_{d=0}^{4} \left(\dbinom{13}{d}~\dbinom{39}{10-d} - \dbinom{12}{d}~\dbinom{36}{10-d} \right)}{\dbinom{52}{10}} \end{align}$$